# Finishing basement... level floors with SLC or install stud wall first?

Tags: basement, floor

Basement floor isn't too far off... wondering if I should get the stud wall done first or level the floor first....

Comment: Every basement floor has waves and imperfections. Unless you have variances that are noticeable in your feet, I wouldn't bother leveling.

Answer (score 1):

You will have better surface to screw/nail bottom plate working on original concrete as is. You can and should always level before getting floor done.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter unless it is really far off.  Also leveling isn't a must do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the floor first. You'll have an easier time with the wall and you won't have to try to level against wooden studs.